# Can 2 different objects created in Java have same this when their hashcode is same?

Tags: java, object, hashcode, equality

In Java, I created 2 different objects (say Person class) and I had overridden the hashCode and equals method.

The two objects were having same hashcode and contents of them were identical.

I displayed the this reference of the 2 objects but both the objects had same value for this. How could this be possible?

Please explain this concept as I had thought whenever we create objects then this reference will ALWAYS be UNIQUE.

Is that when 2 objects have SAME hashcode will this reference RETURN the same value?

```
import java.util.*;
class Complex  extends Object{ 
    private double re, im;

    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }  
    public void  display() {         
         String str = "Address of  object is " + this +" Hashcode is " +hashCode() +" Real " +re+" Imaginary "+im;
         System.out.println(str);
    }
    // Overriding equals method
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        // If the object is compared with itself then return true  
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }     

        // typecast o to Complex so that we can compare data members 
        Complex c = (Complex) o;

        // Compare the data members and return accordingly 
        return Double.compare(re, c.re) == 0 && Double.compare(im, c.im) == 0;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(im,re);
    }
}

// Driver class to test the Complex class
public class ComplexEqualsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex c1 = new Complex(10D, 15.01D);
        Complex c2 = new Complex(10D, 15.01D);
        c1.display();
        c2.display();
        if (c1 == c2)
            System.out.println("Equal  == operator ");
        else
            System.out.println("NOT Equal using == operator ");     

        if (c1.equals(c2)) {
            System.out.println("Equal - using equals method ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Equal -  using equals method ");            
        }
        System.out.println("\nWatch this !!!! ");
       Complex c3 = c1;
        c1.display();
        c3.display();
        if (c1 == c3)
            System.out.println("Equal  == operator ");
        else
            System.out.println("NOT Equal using == operator ");     

        if (c1.equals(c3)) {
            System.out.println("Equal - using equals method ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Equal -  using equals method ");            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ***have the same this...*** what do you mean?

Comment: Please, post your code.

Comment: I'm curious how you even tested whatever you're trying to ask.  Can you show an actual example?

Comment: Ok, you've included your code.  Now what in your code are you talking about?  What is behaving surprisingly?

Comment: Concatenating `this` into a string does not constitute obtaining its address. Nothing does. There is nothing here that supports your contention.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to extend Object class as you have done in your code. By default, every class in Java extends Object class.

Answer (score 2):

> Can two different objects created in Java have same `this`

No, by definition.

> when their hashCode is the same?

Irrelevant.

> I displayed the this reference of the 2 objects but both the objects had same value for this. How could this be possible?

It isn't. There is no way in Java that you *can* display the 'value' of `this`. You deceived yourself somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Any two Objects created separately can never have same memory reference.

> Please explain this concept as I had thought whenever we create objects then this reference will ALWAYS be UNIQUE.

I think you would have put the *this* keyword inside the SysOut statement as below,

```
System.out.println(this);
```

Above statement would have caused the toString() to execute on the corresponding Object. Now the default implementation of toString() in Object class is as below.

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Since you have overridden hashCode() to return identical values for the two Objects you created, toString() returns the same value for both the Objects. Hence your seeing same value being printed by the SysOut.

Comment: If you want to print the "original" hashCode, you could call `System.identityHashCode(this))`

Comment: Thanks for the toString comment. Infact In the above code I added this

Comment: public String toString() {
  return this + " ";
 }

Comment: I am getting the stackoverflow runtime error when that code is executed

Comment: That's because, this keyword inside toString() recursevely calls toString(). This goes into indefinite method calls resulting in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing concepts, hashcode has NOTHING to do in relation to equality of instances...

2 diferent objects can for sure have the same hashcode and they dont need to be equal...

consider this code:

```
System.out.println("Aa".hashCode());
System.out.println("BB".hashCode());
```

as you can see both strings are totally different but have the same hashcode ***2112***

imagine you are an object, and the hash code is just your birthday

you can find another person in this world that is NOT you but share the same b-day...

On the other hand, you and your clone are not just the same person, but yor share the same information and the same b-day or hashcode...

Comment: D:\SarlakG1>java ComplexEqualsDemo
Address of  object is Complex@57a1e886 Hashcode is 1470228614 Real 10.0 Imaginary 15.01
Address of  object is Complex@57a1e886 Hashcode is 1470228614 Real 10.0 Imaginary 15.01
NOT Equal using == operator
Equal - using equals method

Watch this !!!!
Address of  object is Complex@57a1e886 Hashcode is 1470228614 Real 10.0 Imaginary 15.01
Address of  object is Complex@57a1e886 Hashcode is 1470228614 Real 10.0 Imaginary 15.01
Equal  == operator
Equal - using equals method

Comment: When the hashcode is same then when this is displayed it shows the same value even though the objects are different. that is my question how can 2 distinct object have same this reference value when their hashcode is same?

Comment: they can not, if you are printing **this** 2 times and getting a different value, then that means your object changed or is just another object..

Comment: @Vishwanath See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

as per the java documentation

The general contract of hashCode is:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>   consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>   of the same application.
>
> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>   calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.
>
> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the
>   equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>   each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>   However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>   integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>   hash tables.

As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

you can refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--